# Canvas stops working when <audio> is added

Tags: javascript, html, web, audio

I have this canvas with an animation, but when I add background sound for the animation, the animation stops working, it does not start, it seems like the canvas is disabled or something like that

It seems like that the  tag creates another  that stops the one with the animation working.
I tried moving from  to  the sound but it acts the same

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <script src="../js/rocket.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
                background: #222;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
        <audio src="../sound.mp3" autoplay="true" type="audio/mpeg">
    <body>
        <canvas id="playground" width="1300" height="650"></canvas>
    </body>

</html>
```

I would like to have the sound playing during the animation in the canvas

Comment: you arnt closing your audio tag. add a  </audio>

Comment: Does it work if you put the audio tag inside the body tags?